# Rails categorization ordering position

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, database-design

I have a **List** model in which we can add many **Product**. Each of these **Product** is linked to a sub-level **Category** (that has a `parent_id: not-nil`).

How could I order the position of the Category and Sub-Category inside a list ?

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
  has_many :categories, through: :products
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :category

  after_save    :perform_list_category_synchronization
  after_destroy :perform_list_category_synchronization
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categories, primary_key: :parent_id,
                        foreign_key: :id
  belongs_to :category, optional: true
  has_many :products
end
```

My guess would be to create a model like this where every time that we change a **Product** we check that we have a unique element in the table **ListCategory** containing the category_id of that product, if not, we create it. If the product is deleted and no other product is mentioning this category_id, we delete the record in the **ListCategory**.

If feel this is really complicated...

```
class ListCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :category
end
```

I also though about another option where I would create an association model, then when I want to update the position, I update all the records at once.

[image]

```
class ProductCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Do you have a solution to recommend ?

Comment: I would use a before_save callback to do what you are looking for.  That way you can check for whatever you want before it gets saved to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I might be mis-reading your comments, but if a **Product** has only one **Category**, then you should be able to store the **Category** and the `position` and **Product**:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :category

  after_save    :perform_list_category_synchronization
  after_destroy :perform_list_category_synchronization
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Category', primary_key: :parent_id,
                        foreign_key: :id
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Category', optional: true
  has_many :products
end
```

If you're re-using the **Product**s on different **List**s, then you'll probably need a different change along the lines of:

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :list_products
  has_many :categories, through: :list_products
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :list_products
end

class ListProduct < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :product

  after_save    :perform_list_category_synchronization
  after_destroy :perform_list_category_synchronization
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Category', primary_key: :parent_id,
                        foreign_key: :id
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Category', optional: true
  has_many :list_products
end
```

you would then sort the **ListProduct** with the `position`, which wouldn't affect any other **List**, **Product** or **Category**